# Accessing JOption Pane's button to add MouseListener to them

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Right, I thought this would be relatively simple by using `.getComponents()` on the Component which would return the `JPanel` of the `JOptionPane` and them retrieve the `JButton`s by using that method again with the `JPanel` however I am facing difficulties.

I want to use a mouse listener on the `JOptionPane` buttons so that I can change the color of the button on rollover.  Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

This is my class so far ..

```
package rsapp.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class RSJPaneComponent extends JOptionPane {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 13453253L;
    private JOptionPane j=this;
    final Color WHITE = Color.WHITE;


    public RSJPaneComponent(){
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",WHITE);
        UIManager.put("Panel.background",WHITE);
        UIManager.put("Button.background",WHITE);
        UIManager.put("Button.foreground",new Color(85,153,187));
        UIManager.put("activeCaption", WHITE);
    }

    protected String initJPaneInput(final JFrame f, final String message){
        return j.showInputDialog(f,message);
    }

    public int generateDialog(int error_code, String title_message, String message, final JFrame f){
        return  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                f,
                message,
                "Error "+error_code+": "+title_message,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew: You should post this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: How would I do this using a JDialog?  I'm not asking for code, just some useful methods to use or concepts of how to do it.

Comment: @HFOE Done.  @unleashed Please be sure to use code formatting in future posts. To use it, select the code sample and click the `{}` button. Check the code appears as you expect in the preview area below the message posting form.

Comment: Though you were not asking for code, I added some.  Sometimes I find it easier & quicker to code an example, than to describe the process.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Use a `JDialog`. Long experience tells me that while a `JOptionPane` is a powerful & handy component, once it comes to customizing it, you are better off simply using a `JDialog`.

---

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class CustomDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Show Custom Dialog");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", true);

                JPanel mainGui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                mainGui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
                mainGui.add( new JLabel("Contents go here"), BorderLayout.CENTER );

                JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                mainGui.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JButton close = new JButton("Close");
                close.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                } );

                buttonPanel.add(close);

                frame.setVisible(true);

                dialog.setContentPane(mainGui);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

---

### Screen Shot

[image]

---

Note that this example does not yet have all the functionality built-in to a `JOptionPane`.

For example, if a `JOptionPane` is open and the user presses the escape key, the dialog will be dismissed.  You might add that functionality using a `KeyListener` or `ActionMap`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the simple example,can now implement what I needed.

Comment: +1 Very good answer. @unleashed go ahead accept it. You won't find a better solution for your problem.